# How can i fetch a record from HTTP request, in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

My listDepartment function works like fetch my all record from database and display me, I put a search bar also, but after implementing search bar code it didn't display me any records.

here is my controller file

```
public function listDepartment(Request $request)
    {
        $listOfDepartment = $request->input('search');
        $listOfDepartment=Department::where('nameOfDepartment', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('search')}%")
            ->orwhere('createdBy', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('search')}%")->orderBy('nameOfDepartment', 'ASC')->paginate(2);  

        $listOfDepartment->appends (array('search'=>Input::get('search')));

        return view('pages.department', compact('listOfDepartment'));
    }
```

I want that if i didn't search anything be default it display me all the record from my department collection
will anyone help please???

and how can I handle if i have more than one field like this

```
public function listOfLeave(Request $request)
    {
        $search = [$request->input('name'), $request->input('status'),];

        $allLeaves = null;
        if (!empty($search))
        {
            $allLeaves=LeaveManagement::where('username', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('name')}%")->orderBy('username', 'ASC')  
                                    ->orWhere('typeOfLeave', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('leaveType')}%")->orderBy('typeOfLeave', 'ASC')
                                    ->orWhere('typeOfLeave', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('leaveType')}%")->orderBy('typeOfLeave', 'ASC')
                                    ->orWhere('startDate', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('appliedDate')}%")->orderBy('startDate', 'ASC')
                                    ->orWhere('status', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('status')}%")->orderBy('status', 'ASC')->paginate(2);

            return view('pages.newleaverequest')->with(['allLeaves'=>$allLeaves]);  
        }
        else 
        {
            $allLeaves=LeaveManagement::orderBy('username', 'ASC')->paginate(5);  
        }

        $allLeaves->appends(array('name'=>Input::get('name')));

        return view('pages.newleaverequest', compact('allLeaves'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public function listDepartment(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->input('search');
    $listOfDepartment = null;
    if (!empty($search){
        $listOfDepartment=Department::where('nameOfDepartment', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('search')}%")
        ->orwhere('createdBy', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('search')}%")->orderBy('nameOfDepartment', 'ASC')->paginate(2);  
    }
    else {
        $listOfDepartment=Department::orderBy('nameOfDepartment', 'ASC')->paginate(2);  
    }


    $listOfDepartment->appends(array('search'=>Input::get('search')));

    return view('pages.department', compact('listOfDepartment'));
}
```

Please replace the `paginate` part of the statement with actual code you've written for.

For more than one fields:

```
public function listOfLeave(Request $request)
{
        $allLeaves = null;
        if (
            !empty($request->input('name')) || 
            !empty($request->input('leaveType')) || 
            !empty($request->input('appliedDate')) || 
            !empty($request->input('status'))       
        )
        {
            $flg = false; 

            if (!empty($request->input('name'))){
                $flg = true; 
                $allLeaves=LeaveManagement::where('username', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('name')}%");
            }

            if (!empty($request->input('leaveType'))){
                if($flg){
                    $allLeaves=$allLeaves->orWhere('typeOfLeave', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('leaveType')}%");
                }
                else {
                    $allLeaves=LeaveManagement::where('typeOfLeave', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('leaveType')}%");
                }
            }

            if (!empty($request->input('appliedDate'))){
                if($flg){
                    $allLeaves=$allLeaves->orWhere('appliedDate', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('appliedDate')}%");
                }
                else {
                    $allLeaves=LeaveManagement::where('appliedDate', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('appliedDate')}%");
                }
            }

            if (!empty($request->input('status'))){
                if($flg){
                    $allLeaves=$allLeaves->orWhere('status', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('status')}%");
                }
                else {
                    $allLeaves=LeaveManagement::where('status', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('status')}%");
                }
            }

            $allLeaves = $allLeaves->orderBy('username', 'ASC')
                                    ->orderBy('typeOfLeave', 'ASC')
                                    ->orderBy('appliedDate', 'ASC')
                                    ->orderBy('status', 'ASC')
                                    ->paginate(2);

            return view('pages.newleaverequest')->with(['allLeaves'=>$allLeaves]);  
        }
        else 
        {
            $allLeaves=LeaveManagement::orderBy('username', 'ASC')->paginate(5);  
        }

        $allLeaves->appends(array('name'=>Input::get('name')));

        return view('pages.newleaverequest', compact('allLeaves'));
}
```

Comment: will you please help how can i handle if i have more than 1 field??
i updated question...

Comment: @John_rees so you want to either search by name or status? Can you explain exact criteria on which fields do you want to search?

Comment: I want to search by name or status or leaveType or appliedDate I have 4 fields to search

Comment: OK. So if any of 4 fields present in the request then search should be applied for that field, else not. Correct me?

Comment: @John_rees please check the answer, I have appended a new function into it.

Comment: Got it Sir, Thanks a ton, you just save my day. Thanks a ton man

Comment: Umm hey can u please help How can I get all the records between the start date and end date in laravel?